# Extracting word document with styles associated to the content

Tags: formatting, text-mining, text-extraction, python-docx

I'm trying to extract the format of a word document containing text in different fonts and font-sizes, images, comments etc. I have used `zipfile` module to extract the XML files of the word document.

XML files are:

```
['[Content_Types].xml',
 '_rels/.rels',
 'word/_rels/document.xml.rels',
 'word/document.xml',
 'word/footer2.xml',
 'word/header1.xml',
 'word/footer1.xml',
 'word/endnotes.xml',
 'word/footnotes.xml',
 'word/_rels/header1.xml.rels',
 'word/header2.xml',
 'word/_rels/header2.xml.rels',
 'word/embeddings/Microsoft_Word_97_-_2003_Document1.doc',
 'word/media/image3.wmf',
 'word/media/image2.emf',
 'word/theme/theme1.xml',
 'word/media/image1.png',
 'word/embeddings/oleObject1.bin',
 'word/comments.xml',
 'word/settings.xml',
 'word/styles.xml',
 'customXml/itemProps1.xml',
 'word/numbering.xml',
 'customXml/_rels/item1.xml.rels',
 'customXml/item1.xml',
 'docProps/app.xml',
 'word/stylesWithEffects.xml',
 'word/webSettings.xml',
 'word/fontTable.xml',
 'docProps/core.xml',
 'docProps/custom.xml']
```

I'm unable to understand the styles associated with the content present in `word/document.xml`.

I'm trying to encapsulate the results in the following manner:

```
{
    "text": "some-text-in-document",
    "font": "some-font",
    "font_size": 10,
    "some_field": "some-more-value",
    ...
}
```

Tried using `python-docx` to get the fonts and font-sizes but mostly the value is `None`

here's the code snippet:

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
styles = document.styles
#print(styles.default)
paragraph_styles = [s for s in styles if s.type == WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH]
for style in paragraph_styles:
    #print(style.font.name)
    if(style.font.name):
        print(style.font.name, style.font.size)

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    #print(paragraph.text)
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        print(run.text)
        font = run.style.font
        print(font.size)
```

Results are mostly `None` for font and size.

Answer (score 0):

A value of `None` for `style` means `Normal`.

All paragraphs have a style, it's just that most have the same style, so Word doesn't spell it out for that majority case, perhaps to save space.

Comment: What is `Normal`? Any specific `font-name` and `font-size`! Any attribute from which I can derive default values for `font-name` and `font-size`?

Comment: `Normal` is the base paragraph style in a Word document. All new documents have this style and by default, it is applied when no other style has been specified. Look in any Word document and you'll find it. You can also retrieve it in `python-docx` by that name `normal = document.styles["Normal"]` and interrogate its properties. Unfortunately, the font size, for example, may very well be `None`, meaning "the document default font size", which I don't believe can be retrieved via the API yet.